how to integrate react-hook-form with custom mui file upload button
const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

<Grid xs={8}>
    <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Upload File</Typography>
    <FormControl size="small" sx={{ mr: 2 }}>
    <Button component="label" variant="contained">Choose File
            <input
        type="file"
        hidden
            required 
                accept=".pdf,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/tiff"
            />
    </Button>
    </FormControl>
    {file && <FormLabel>{file.name}</FormLabel>}
</Grid>

I want to integrate react-hook-form with my custom mui file upload button. When a file is selected, the file name will be displayed next to the button.
After studying the react-hook-form documentation, I use Controller to register the component and updated codes are shown below.
const { control } = useForm();
<Grid xs={8}>
    <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Upload File</Typography>
    <FormControl size="small" sx={{ mr: 2 }}>
        <Controller
            name="file"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
                <Button component="label" variant="contained">Choose File
                    <input
                        {...field}
                type="file"
                hidden
                    required 
                        accept=".pdf,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/tiff"
                    />
            </Button>
            )
        />
    </FormControl>
    {file && <FormLabel>{file.name}</FormLabel>}
</Grid>

However, when a file is selected, the file name can't be displayed. I asked Poe and it gives me following two sets of codes.
Set 1:
const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
    if (field.value?.[0]) {
    setFileName(field.value[0].name);
    } else {
    setFileName('');
    }
}, [field.value]);

<Grid xs={8}>
    <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Upload File</Typography>
    <FormControl size="small" sx={{ mr: 2 }}>
        <Controller
            name="file"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
                <Button component="label" variant="contained">Choose File
                    <input
                        {...field}
                type="file"
                hidden
                    required 
                        accept=".pdf,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/tiff"
                    />
            </Button>
            )
        />
    </FormControl>
    <FormLabel>{fileName}</FormLabel>
</Grid>

Set 2:
const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");
const { control, register } = useForm();
useEffect(() => {
    if (register('file').value?.[0]) {
    setFileName(register('file').value[0].name);
    } else {
    setFileName('');
    }
}, [register('file').value]);

<Grid xs={8}>
    <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Upload File</Typography>
    <FormControl size="small" sx={{ mr: 2 }}>
        <Controller
            name="file"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
                <Button component="label" variant="contained">Choose File
                    <input
                        {...field}
                type="file"
                hidden
                    required 
                        accept=".pdf,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/tiff"
                    />
            </Button>
            )
        />
    </FormControl>
    <FormLabel>{fileName}</FormLabel>
</Grid>

However, neither sets of codes work. Are my codes of using Controller wrong? How can the file name be displayed?
